# What is the right way to read cache after writing to cache from react apollo-client?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I have created a basic example that reads data from a graphql server.
I have noticed my network calls make a request after I have run my mutation.
I am trying to update the cache to prevent that network call but when I then try to read the cache.

This method works to retrieve data, but it does not automatically read from the cache:

## useQuery

```js
 const { data } = useQuery(GET_PLAYERS);
```

## useQuery with @client directive to indicate get cache - fails

```js
const GET_PLAYERS = gql`
  query getPlayers {
    players @client {
      __typename
      _id
      name
      score
    }
  }
`;
 const { data } = useQuery(GET_PLAYERS);
```

> err =
> MissingFieldError {message: "Can't find field 'players' on ROOT_QUERY object", path: Array(1), query: {…}, variables: {…}}
> message: "Can't find field 'players' on ROOT_QUERY object"

## using client.readQuery() returns nothing on both load and after mutation is still no results:

```js
  const obj = client.readQuery({ query: GET_PLAYERS });
```

Here is my full code.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import 'cross-fetch/polyfill'; // patch for tests: Error: fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for your environment
import {
  gql,
  useQuery,
  useMutation,
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider
} from '@apollo/client';

const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/graphql';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const ADD_PLAYER = gql`
  mutation AddPlayer($name: String!) {
    addPlayer(player: { name: $name }) {
      _id
      name
      score
    }
  }
`;

// example with directive = @client to try to get cached version
// const GET_PLAYERS = gql`
//   query getPlayers {
//     players @client {
//       __typename
//       _id
//       name
//       score
//     }
//   }
// `;

const GET_PLAYERS = gql`
  query getPlayers {
    players {
      _id
      name
      score
    }
  }
`;

interface IData {
  data: {
    players: Array<{ name: string }>;
  };
  loading: boolean;
}

interface IPlayer {
  name: string | null;
}

const App: FC = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_PLAYERS);
  // const { data } = client.readQuery({ query: GET_PLAYERS });
  // console.log('obj = ', obj);
  // const data = obj && obj.data;

  const [addPlayer] = useMutation(ADD_PLAYER, {
    update: (cache, { data: mutationData }) => {
      try {
        const cacheGetPlayers: { players: Array<IPlayer> } | null = cache.readQuery({
          query: GET_PLAYERS
        });

        const cachePlayers: Array<IPlayer> = (cacheGetPlayers && cacheGetPlayers.players) || [
          { name: null }
        ];

        let playersUpdated: Array<IPlayer> = { ...cachePlayers };

        const player = mutationData.addPlayer;

        if (player) {
          // ie not already existing !!!

          if (playersUpdated) {
            if (!cachePlayers.find((item: IPlayer) => player.name !== item.name)) {
              playersUpdated.push(player);
            }
          } else {
            playersUpdated = [player];
          }
          cache.writeQuery({
            query: GET_PLAYERS,
            data: {
              getPlayers: {
                players: playersUpdated
              }
            }
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('err = ', err);
      }
    }
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    const name = 'mary';

    addPlayer({
      variables: { name },
      // example data:
      // optimisticResponse: {
      //   __typename: 'Mutation',
      //   addPlayer: {
      //     _id: ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003'), // 4edd40c86762e0fb12000003
      //     score: 0,
      //     name
      //   }
      // },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_PLAYERS }]
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      list of existing names = {data &&
        data.players instanceof Array &&
        data.players.map((item: { name: string }) => `,${item.name}`)}

      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click to add player
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Prov = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);

export default Prov;
```

Any advice, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, @client directive just uses for querying data that you should initiate a `players` field in the cache with the `__typename`. Like this:

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link,
})

cache.writeData({
    data: {
    players: {
      items: [],
      __typename: Player
    }
  },
})

...

const GET_PLAYERS = gql`
  query {
    players @client {
      __typename
      items {
        _id
        name
        score
      }
    }
  }
`;
 const { data } = useQuery(GET_PLAYERS);
```

Secondly, if you want to update the cache after a [mutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usemutation) you should use `update` option. Like this:

```js
useMutation(UPDATE_PLAYER, {
      update(cache, { data: { player } }) {
        const { players } = cache.readQuery(options)
        cache.writeQuery({
          ...options,
          data: {
            players: { ...players, items: [player, ...players.items] },
          },
        })
      },
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Just looking this up. It seems there are several ways to do things and there are lacking full examples on the apollo site. Your example seems to be relating to - apollo-link-state which is another way to writeData. I am looking into this but I would still like to know how to write cache in both ways - ie using @apollo/client include.